# Differences in g++ Unix Compiler and Visual Studio (Specifically RegEx)

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio, unix

While working on a project to design my own assembler (part of a multi part computer I'm building), I ran into the following problem in runtime for two different c++ compilers:

On the following input:

```
//inputfile.asm
//This is a sample line
//This is a sample/ line/ 2
@foo     //it is not necessary to understand these lines, only the
         //comment portion in question
D=M
```

For some reason the code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
     std::string line;
     std::vector<std::string> my_vector;
     std::vector<int> lineComments;

     std::ifstream inFile("inputfile.asm");

     while (!inFile.eof()) {
         std::getline(inFile, line);
         my_vector.push_back(line);
     }

     std::regex lineComment{ R"(.*\/\/.*)" };
     for (int i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++) {
             if (regex_match(my_vector.at(i), lineComment)) {
                 lineComments.push_back(i);
             }
     }
}
```

worked perfectly fine and produced logical output (filling my lineComments vector with the troublesome lines I would handle later) when compiled and run in Visual Studio, however when I attempted to move to this a Unix server, this same code could not apparently recognize the "//" token (I tried with and without backslashes preceding each).

I've read numerous threads going over how compilation varies between the two but do not understand how this same code compiled and ran and *did not perform similar operations* on the input. Are the RegEx libraries somehow different within these two separate compilers? I was under the impression RegEx was a little more universal within c++ than this.

Additional Info: Attempted to compile in Unix using c++11, c++14, and c++17 in case that was the issue, none worked.

Comment: Can you show a sample initialization of `my_vector` such that this becomes a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry about that! Just fixed it now.

Comment: I was hoping for some sample lines :D

Comment: Versions of `g++` prior to 4.9 had non-working `#include <regex>`. Try `boost::regex` instead. You do not need to quote `/`.

Comment: Do you mean all of `#include <regex>` or for specific instances? I used regex for some different patterns in my code, and this was the only one that was broken.